# Flask 404 Not Found error, yet the sublink exists in the python file

Tags: python, html, flask

Hello everyone thanks for taking the time to read and possibly help me out.

I'm running flask and my index page works just fine but now I am trying to setup some extra pages for my site and I get a 404 error even though I am fairly certain I have them set up correctly in the python application file.

Here are the error logs:

```
2017-12-23 16:32:43,232: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'laws'. Did you mean 'search' instead?
2017-12-23 16:32:43,232: File "/home/*****/.virtualenvs/zones4drones/lib/python3.6/site-‌​packages/flask/app.p‌​y", line 1997, in call
```

I'm wondering if it may have something to do with DNS?  Or maybe the server host?  Because I have run it inside a test environment (CS50 IDE) and the links do indeed work.

Here's the flask app:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from tempfile impor t gettempdir
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue

import time

# configure application
app = Flask(__name__)
#JSGlue(app)

# configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = gettempdir()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

# ensure responses aren't cached
if app.config["DEBUG"]:
    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        response.headers["Expires"] = 0
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
        return response

Session(app)

itemCount = 0
vehicleCount = 0

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/laws', methods=['GET'])
def laws():
    return render_template("laws.html")

@app.route('/about', methods=['GET'])
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    """Search for items that match query."""

    conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/extinkt/zones4drones/airports2.db')
    db = conn.cursor()

    a = float(request.args.get("swLat"))
    b = float(request.args.get("swLong"))
    c = float(request.args.get("neLat"))
    d = float(request.args.get("neLong"))

    if (a < 0): a += .1
    else:       a -= .1

    if (b < 0): b -= .1
    else:       b += .1

    if (c < 0): c -= .1
    else:       c += .1

    if (d < 0): d += .1
    else:       d -= .1

    #print(a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ", " + d)

    db.execute("""SELECT latitude, longitude, name, class FROM airports WHERE
                (CASE WHEN {0} < {2}
                    THEN latitude BETWEEN {0} AND {2}
                    ELSE latitude BETWEEN {2} AND {0}
                END)
                AND
                (CASE WHEN {1} < {3}
                    THEN longitude BETWEEN {1} AND {3}
                    ELSE longitude BETWEEN {3} AND {1}
                END)
                AND (type != 'heliport' AND type != 'balloonport' AND type != 'closed')""".format(a, b, c, d))

    airports = db.fetchall()

    db.close()
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(airports)
```

Since it was asked that I include the index.html here it is (along with the layout.html that wraps index.html):

```
{% block main %}
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="left-bar">
                <div id="flightCheckBox">
                    <div id="listTitle">
                        <img id="listTitleImg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/listTitle.png') }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="checklist">
                        <div id="listItem">
                            <div class="check">All wiring connections are intact</div>
                            <div class="check">Battery charged and securely strapped, no loose wires</div>
                            <div class="check">Well clear of all obstructions (Trees, Phone Lines, Radio Interference)</div>
                            <div class="check">No people/animals in flight path (Have a spotter if unsure)</div>
                            <div class="check">Not impeeding any emergency operations (Fires, Accidents, Rescues)</div>
                            <div class="check">Weather conditions suitable for flight (Rain, Wind, Fog) </div>
                            <div class="check">Location check complete (not within 5 miles of an Airport)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="checkboxes">
                            <div id="firstCheckbox" class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div class="checkbox"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                            <div id="locationCheck" class="checkbox"><img id="locationCheckImg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/unchecked.png') }}"/></div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div id="resultImg">
                        <img id="resultCheckImg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/flightCheckIncomplete2.png') }}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="videoFull">
                    <div id="titleDiv"><img id="videoTitle" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/videoTitle.png') }}"/></div>
                    <div id="videoWrapper">
                        <video id="videoFrame" controls="controls" autoplay="true" name="Steetly Session" 
                        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='video/steetley-edit.mov') }}"></video>
                        <!-- <iframe id="videoFrame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TnXZEcU7PBw?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="infoBox">
                    <p class="info2"style="padding-top: 10px">Want to see your video up there?</p>
                    <p class="info2">Click <a href=''>HERE</a> to submit your video</p>
                    <p class="info2">for a chance to be displayed!</p>
                    <p class="info2" style="padding-top: 18px">Did we miss a zone or screw something up?</p>
                    <p class="info2">It happens.  Let us know, <a href=''>HERE</a>!</p>
                <!--
                    <p class="info2" style="padding-top: 18px">If you like what we're doing here,</p>
                    <p class="info2">consider buying us a coffee or two.</p>
                    <div id="ko-fi" align="center"><script type='text/javascript' src='https://ko-fi.com/widgets/widget_2.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>kofiwidget2.init('Buy Us a Coffee', '#45829E', 'S6S45ZA5');kofiwidget2.draw();</script></div>
                -->
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id="right-bar">
                <!-- Map -->
                <div id="map">

                    <!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial -->
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

                    <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms -->
                    <form id="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="q" style="color: #26c9dc">Search Locations</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Search Locations" autocomplete="off" type="text"/>

                        <div id="geoLocate">
                            <button id="geoButton"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/geoLocate.png') }}" height="20px" /></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="legend">
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="head"><img class="circle" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/circle_blue.png') }}"/></th>
                            <td><p class="zoneInfo">Commercial Airports</p></td>
                            <td class="head"><img class="circle" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/circle_red.png') }}"/></td>
                            <td><p class="zoneInfo">Military Airports</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="head"><img class="circle" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/circle_yellow.png') }}"/></th>
                            <td><p class="zoneInfo">National Parks</p></td>
                            <td class="head"><img class="circle" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/circle_green.png') }}"/></td>
                            <td><p class="zoneInfo">Civilian Marked Zones</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the layout.html which wraps each page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}">

        <!-- http://jquery.com/ -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        {% block script %}{% endblock %}

        {% block css %}{% endblock %}

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

</FRAMESET>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="header-content">
                    <div id="logo" align="left">
                        <img id="logoImg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo3.png') }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"> 
                            <img class="option" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/checklist.png') }}"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('laws') }}">
                            <img class="option" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/laws.png') }}"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">
                            <img class="option" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/about.png') }}"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="seperator-bar"></div>
            </div>

            <main>
                {% block main %}{% endblock %}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is laws.html (which doesnt have any content yet, Im just trying to make it load), in case that helps:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block css %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}  
    <!-- app's own JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    Zones 4 Drones
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the output from ls inside the templates directory of the server:

```
14:26 ~/zones4drones/templates $ ls
about.html  index.html  laws.html  layout.html
```

All 4 of those files have permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

If seeing the site might help, its located at [zonesfordrones.com](https://www.zonesfordrones.com).  The links I'm trying to use are on the top bar.

I know there's already a lot of topics on this subject, but I assure you I've read them all (or at least the vast majority).  Most of them are only about an index file no extra links, and the rest say it's a permissions problem.  So if anyone has any ideas I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Is there anything that might help in the log files?

Comment: Good call, hadn't checked that.  Unfortunately the error doesn't seem too descriptive.  Here it is:                                                                                          `2017-12-23 16:32:43,232: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'laws'. Did you mean 'search' instead?
2017-12-23 16:32:43,232:   File "/home/extinkt/.virtualenvs/zones4drones/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
2017-12-23 16:32:43,232:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)`

Comment: Remove the log and add the content of your index.html question

Comment: Have you tried non-scientific approach like throwing trailing slashes around? See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules (not the linked paragraph, but the one below, about unique and redirection things). Though it would not explain why search works (it returns a JSON if I call it manually and supply the parameters). Another one: is it sure that index.html comes from the folder you have listed here? Perhaps there is another index.html somewhere else, without the happy company of the other files. Also, you could compare the logs of a successful and a non-successful request.

Comment: @tevemadar thanks for that suggestion, I tried adding trailing /'s and unfortuantely got the same error.  I've tried basically every combination I can think of given flask's format and that doesnt seem to be solving the problems.  I also checked to ensure that index.html was indeed not anywhere else on the server and it does look to be only in that one place.

Comment: That all being said, I added the HTML pages in question as per @Espoir Murhabazi's request.  But I'm fairly certain the HTML pages are not the problem, it's the sublinks I'm trying to use.   Because I've tried telling those links just to render index.html because I know that is a working page, but I still get the 404 error.  Needless to say, I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Personally I would try with single-file static content. Perhaps it is not the routing which fails, but the content generation. That </FRAMESET> in the middle of nowhere is really lovely for example.

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely admit it's all a bit sloppy in it's current state and I'll try and clean that up now and see if it fixes things.  However I'm not too optimistic it will to be honest, because I've tried using the index.html page, which I know for sure works, instead of laws.html or about.html and the error still occurs.  It's looking like it must be some small detail somewhere though, so I'm going to go ahead and read through everything again while trying to clean some stuff up.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: the code is so messy i can't even look for what i would look for. so you have your application, and only have 404 when you want to redirect to `laws`? show us how you want to redirect there. remove the unnecessary code, so we don't have to hunt for problem.

Comment: do you have your link's in your local testing environment? maybe your nginx or uwsgi is messed up something(or what ever you are using to deploy)?

Comment: Well..  I feel like an idiot here guys.  Turns out that with the host PythonAnywhere you have to click the "reload site" button on their page for changes in the Flask python file to propagate.  I had no idea this was the case since I hadn't done any changes to the application file since I started using them and the changes to HTML, CSS and Javascript would propagate without reloading.  Sorry for the waste of time everyone, but I must say I'm pretty ecstatic that it's working now after about 3 days of being at a stalemate.  Now to work on cleaning up my code since it's evidently not even par.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that with the host PythonAnywhere you have to click the "reload site" button on their page for changes in the Flask python file to propagate. I had no idea this was the case since I hadn't done any changes to the application file since I started using them as a host.  Since the changes to HTML, CSS and Javascript propagate without reloading, I never realized that fact.  Hopefully if you're having this problem you see this post before wasting 3 days on this like I did... :P